# Can the Antminer S3 mine Bitcoin using Scrypt algorithm?

Tags: scrypt, antminer, nicehash

Because I can use my PC to mine Bitcoin using the Scrypt algorithm. I use NiceHash. They have an option to select which algorithm we want to use. So I was wondering, once I get my Antminer S3, is it possible to point it to NiceHash's Scrypt stratum and mine using the Scrypt algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Bitcoin does not use Scrypt, so you cannot use something that mines Scrypt to mine Bitcoin. Furthermore, the Antminer S3 is a Bitcoin miner, it can only mine SHA256d coins, such as Bitcoin. So it cannot even use the Scrypt algorithm or mine any coins that use Scrypt.

Comment: So how does Nicehash work? They have an option to mine using the Scrypt algorithm (bitcoin), and when I use it, my hashing speed jumps from 11 MH/s to 1.7GH/s

Comment: Nicehash will use your hashrate to mine some coin other than Bitcoin, and then convert the earnings to Bitcoin for you.